# SELinux on CentOS not working

Tags: centos, selinux, centos7

i'm new to CentOS and trying to enable SELinux and it's not working after a restart as described on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts.

The only error message I get after each reboot is:

```
master:~# cat /var/log/messages | grep "SELinux"
Jul 14 22:11:48 master kernel: SELinux:  Disabled at boot.
```

As far as Google could tell me this means my config file has SELINUX=0 / SELINUX=disabled. But my config file should be correct:

```
master:~# cat /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

I found it strange that the described /etc/sysconfig/selinux symlink did not exist so it created it pointing to /etc/selinux/config:

```
master:~# ls -l /etc/sysconfig/ | grep selinux
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Jul 14 22:18 selinux -> /etc/selinux/config
```

System Details: freshly installed minimal CentOS 7 with current updates:

```
master:~# uname -a
Linux master 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also installed the packages described at the above link:

```
yum install policycoreutils policycoreutils-python selinux-policy selinux-policy-targeted libselinux-utils setroubleshoot-server setools setools-console mcstrans
```

Any idea how to debug this? I could not find any other way to enable SELinux other than changing the config file and rebooting, what could be wrong?
Could a kernel module be missing?

Edit:

The culprit:

```
master:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=uquota,gquota acpi=ht crashkernel=auto selinux=0 nodmraid rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Comment: Show your `/etc/sysconfig/grub` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SELinux was disabled on your kernel command line, by someone inserting `selinux=0`.

To resolve the problem, remove this from `/etc/sysconfig/grub`, [regenerate your grub configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html#sec-Configuring_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader), and then reboot.

You should also complain to whoever made this image, as this is a really nasty trick to play...

Comment: Thank you :-) It was the default image installed by server4you.de...

Comment: While in general setting `selinux=0` is probably not a great idea there are certain situations where it is perfectly acceptable.  Most HPC cluster compute and non-login nodes will go to great lengths to disable SELinux and any other applications that will generate system/OS overhead.  So while undesirable in this situation, under the right network environment it may be a reasonable thing to do in an effort to improve performance.

Comment: @Matt Perhaps so, but this isn't the case for _most_ people, and thus it should not be the _default_.